# ConstraintViolationException with Hibernate Kotlin

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, exception, spring-data-jpa

I have a SQL table with a UniqueConstraint with the name `unique_entry`. This unique constraint essentially checks if the combination of two specific fields (let's say `foo` and `bar`) are unique. While using Hibernate, if I violate this specific constraint, when I catch the exception, it should be an instance of  `ConstraintViolationException` right? If yes, should this `if` statement be true?

```
catch (e: ConstraintViolationException) {
        if (e.constraintName?.equals("unique_entry", ignoreCase = true) == true) {
           .....
        }
```

Basically, I want to handle the exception in a specific way if that unique constraint  is triggered. Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: The easiest way is to temprarily catch all exceptions (`catch (e: Exception)` instead of `catch (e: ConstraintViolationException)`), put a breakpoint into catch block. Then you force such violation to happen and look what exact type catched exception has in your debugger

Comment: Why don't you try it?